# Invoke a lambda function when another lambda function is deployed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an AWS lambda function that provides configuration objects. Whenever this lambda function is updated(i.e deployed again), I need to trigger another lambda function, that detects changes in those config objects and takes some action. How do I monitor this lambda deployment, which cloud watch event do I need to subscribe to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that your lambda deployments are not managed by [CodeDeploy](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/implementing-safe-aws-lambda-deployments-with-aws-codedeploy/). If so, I would recommend looking into creating a [CloudTrial trial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-create-and-update-a-trail.html).

Once CT trial is created with default settings, it will monitor all [management API calls](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/logging-using-cloudtrail.html) to your lambda function. One of them is `UpdateFunctionCode`. Thus you can create a CloudWatch rule for  `AWS API Call via CloudTrail`. The rule would be triggered on the function update API call.

Example of such a rule:

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.lambda"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": [
      "lambda.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "eventName": [
      "UpdateFunctionCode"
    ]
  }
}
```

Then you can trigger a second lambda, based on the captured update event of the first function.

Comment: Yes, lambda deployments are done using node serverless package. I will try the method you have mentioned here.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Marcin, Where do I specify the particular function name in the rule?

Comment: @pras007 You would have to check the structure of the event object for `UpdateFunctionCode`, and modify based on this. For example for the [DeleteFunction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/logging-using-cloudtrail.html), the function name is in `"requestParameters": {
        "functionName": "basic-node-task" }`.  Sadly, I don't know what is the event structure for `UpdateFunctionCode`. You can run it once as it is and print out the event to cloudwatch logs in lambda function, and check there.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Marcin's suggestion, used console log to print the event. The below rule helped to filter a specific function;

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.lambda"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": [
      "lambda.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "eventName": [
      "UpdateFunctionCode20150331v2"
    ],
    "responseElements": {
      "functionName": [
        "myFunction"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```